# HTML Email : put transparent background color on image and text on it

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to have a text which is on transparent background layer and that background layer is on image.

As I am making HTML Emailer , so can't use `background-image` property. Have to use `img` tag.

How can I do so?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/cover/facebook/thumb/2712_1467715620.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I want a transparent background color layer on the image and some text on the background color layer.

PS: I can't use `div` , `position`. have to stick to `table` tag and **inline css** only.

Thank You.

Comment: why you can't use div?

Comment: I am making HTML Emailer , so some email clients won't support `div` .

Comment: Does it have dynamic data? HTML emails are a real struggle, all I can suggest is trying to make images from the parts that dont have to be dynamic.

Comment: yes. images might get changed based on theme and requirements. so what can be the way to solve it out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two tables for that.

```html
  <table class="main-background" width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#222325" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;   mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" background="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/cover/facebook/thumb/2712_1467715620.jpg">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="300" valign="top" align="center" style="">                            
  <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="container" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background:rgba(245,86,26,0.4);">
  <tbody>  <tr><td>Your Text</td></tr><tr><td>Your Text</td></tr><tr><td>Your Text</td></tr><tr><td>Your Text</td></tr></tbody></table>
  </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Try using this code.